# how to stop the application from opening in android

Tags: android, sms

I am developing a simple SMS Application in android,i am able to send and receive messages.
during receiving of sms i want my application should open whenever the sms comes from a specified number with some notification within the app and it shouldnot open whenever it comes from unspecified number..
what i am able to do is open the app whenever the message comes from the specified number but not able to stop my application from getting invoked(incase of unspecified number).

Help..

Comment: You can not avoid starting your application when you receive an sms, you can avoid starting your activity, which I suspect is what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
if (bundle != null)
        {    
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length]; 

            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){

                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                phNum = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                if("9716009159".equals(phNum)){
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";  
                abortBroadcast();
                }
                else{
                        clearAbortBroadcast();
                }
            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            //Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //---launch the MainActivity--
            Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            mainActivityIntent.putExtra("ph", phNum);
            mainActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);            

            //---send a broadcast to update the SMS received in the activity---
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
            context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }                         
        }
```

The launching of your activity should only happen when the message is from the number you specify. At the moment you launch the activity as long as the message is not null. Instead of the code above, use this:

```
if (bundle != null)
        {    
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length]; 

            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){

                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                phNum = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                if("9716009159".equals(phNum)){
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                    str += " :";
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";

                    //---display the new SMS message---
                    //Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //---launch the MainActivity--
                    Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    mainActivityIntent.putExtra("ph", phNum);
                    mainActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);            

                    //---send a broadcast to update the SMS received in the activity---
                    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                    broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
                    broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
                    context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);  
                    abortBroadcast();
                }
                else{
                    clearAbortBroadcast();
                }
            }
        }                         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to open your application when the SMS comes. Imagine your user playing a game or watching youtube, and when the SMS comes your application appears in the foreground without user expecting it. This is not pleasant for your users. Good practice is to implement a service, that will scan received SMS and check whether number is specified or not. Then if number is specified you can add a notification to the notification bar to make user see the alert. When user clicks on your notification he opens your app and sees the information you provide. Hope this helps you.

Comment: but still i don't understand how will he be able to stop his application from reacting to some unspecified number..?? You gave him a way around for what he is doing, but what about his problem?

Comment: @Sumit, I gave him the way of preventing the application from running when it's not necessary, I think it's better then stopping application when it's already running.

Comment: @videre, I am not able to use your solution code as i am getting an error saying SMS_RECEIVED cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: @abhinav, iam using almost the same code you gave me..i was able to put a if condtion in the same code but that didnot prevented the application from opening up but only the notification part was handled(that is the whenever a msg comes from another number the application was getting invoked but notification was not there)

Comment: @egor, thanks for your suggestion, but i want that the notification should be exclusive to the application and not in the notification bar..

Comment: @egor, with refrence to your post i would like you to suggest me a solution to the problem "Imagine your user playing a game or watching youtube, and when the SMS comes your application appears in the foreground without user expecting it. This is not pleasant for your users. "

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;


    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();// note this line gives your contact number                     
            str += " ::::::::::::::::::::";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";        
        }
    }
```

This code what you are writing in your broad cast reciver
see // code which gives the incoming message number
get the number from there and check the number with the number which you want to restrict if true then dont start you application if false start your application thats it

If you need more assistance comment me

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the sms received event in a broadcastreceiver, not an activity. In the broadcastreceiver's onReceive method you can filter the phone numbers, and if it is a phone number you're interested in, you can launch your activity.

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            if(phone number matches your filter){
                startActivity(your intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to declare the receiver in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

EDIT: The phone number you get from the system probably contains country code, area code etc, and therefore you should compare the strings like this:

```
if(extractedNumber.contains(yourNumber)){
      //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I think your problem lies in this line: if("your number".equals(phNum)). Because of country codes etc. it should be: if(phNum.contains("your number"))

Comment: I found the problem. I have posted another answer, since I think that the information in this answer is still relevant for others.