# Putting of default SMS notification

Tags: android, sms

What I am trying to do is developing an SMS notification system for our own application, whenever the sms is received from a specified number the application gets invoked but the problem is that whenever the sms arrives from any other number then also the application gets invoked and that is undesirable. I would be grateful to hear from u all .

Answer (score 0):

Read this question and answers: [how to stop the application from opening in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678860/how-to-stop-the-application-from-opening-in-android)

Basically you need to extract the number from the message and if it is a number you are interested in, then you start your application, otherwise not.